# What am I looking at?

Tags: star, planet, satellite

I am in Northampton England and every night in the SW sky is a very bright, white light that twinkles. It visibly appears to be moving towards the west but appears pretty much the same start place every night. Could anyone possibly tell me what it might be please?

Comment: Moving west with respect to what?  My usual guess is either there's a daily airplane flight along that path,  or you're looking at a geostationary satellite .

Answer (score 1):

Is it moving straight to the west (i.e. it keeps the same distance from the horizon) or does it 'move with the stars'?

Have you checked an online planetarium like [The Sky Live](https://theskylive.com/planetarium#ra|3.402367700043592|dec|1.963283012898064|fov|62.59999999999999)? Based on the current information, it could just be [Sirius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius), the brightest star in the night sky, or even Venus which is currently in her Evenstar period (but planets generally don't twinkle).

Comment: Well, this *is* England, where the atmosphere is brutally humid & likely to make even the sun twinkle.

Comment: +1 for Venus. Bright. So bright it is notable as something more than a normal star.  As the sky darkens it appears to become brighter (and hence appears to become closer) appears each night (but not always there)  Low in the sky, moves to the west (with the sun) and everything twinkles a bit.